# ListView not scrollable with Sliding up panel library

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

I have a `ListView` of songs and a sliding up panel with buttons, but I can't scroll through the songs. I'm able to scroll when I remove the sliding up panel. I also have a tab layout with tabs, but I can't swipe through the tabs and the only way I cant switch tabs is by tapping the tabs at the top.

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    app:umanoPanelHeight="70dp"
    app:umanoShadowHeight="5dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-    auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <include layout="@layout/songs_layout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="false">

        <include layout="@layout/slideup_nowplaying"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</com.sothree.slidinguppanel.SlidingUpPanelLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have a scrollable view inside of the sliding panel, make sure to set umanoScrollableView attribute on the panel to supported nested scrolling. The panel supports ListView, ScrollView and RecyclerView out of the box

***sothree:umanoScrollableView="@+id/list"***
Where list is the id of the listview